# MVC Rails Planning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm a starting with Rails and I'm building an app that stores Films info, so a user can watch a movie and then give it a grade on the web application.

I have coded up to the Film model, controller and views. Now, I have two questions:

1. Should I need to create a model and a controller for the grading?
2. In that case, should I create it now or should I wait and create first the users model and controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, on the model and controller for Grades. That'd be the most feasible way to keep track of who's graded what. It's really up to you which you make first, but I'd start with Users, since Grades would depend on both Films and Users.

Comment: That's what I was thinking about, thank you very much!